# How to write a dictionary in a file Python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, fwrite

Hi would like to store a dictionary in a file but my code doesn't work.

Here the code:

```
d=open('dict.txt', 'w')
for key, v in dict_ens.iteritems(): # dict_ens is another dict i have
    dict_ens[key]=dict_ens[key][2:]
    if key in enstts: #
       d.write(key, v)
    else : 
       d.write('no key')

d.close()
```

what could be wrong with that???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100125/storing-python-dictionaries, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322273/store-a-dictionary-in-a-file-for-later-retrieval, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201290/how-to-save-a-dictionary-to-a-file-in-python, Lots of duplicates of this Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible ways your code could fail, but without a reproducible example or the error message I can't give you a specific reason.

I would suggest an alternative approach. A simple way to save a dictionary is using the "pickle" library.

To save the dictionary as a pickle file, try this:

```
import pickle
with open('path_and_filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(name_of_dict, handle)
```

You can open a saved dictionary like this:

```
with open('path_and_filename.pickle', 'r') as handle:
    variable_name = pickle.load(handle)
```