# Load the first n items from a pickle file

Tags: python

This may be an unusual thing to do, but I would like to load n items from a pckle file, it can be random, or first or last items.

The reason is that I am testing a neural network that load the pickle file as data and I want the network to run a lot faster (reducing from 100000 items to n) in the testing phase.

Right now I am loading the pickle as:

```
l = pickle.load(open(file, 'rb'))
```

Is there any parameter to load only the first n items?

The file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Only if you saved them to the file individually.

Comment: Oh, I suppose I could just define m = l[1-10] or something.

Comment: possibly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860051/how-to-reduce-the-time-taken-to-load-a-pickle-file-in-python

Answer (score -6, accepted):

This was quite easy actually:

```
n = 100;
l = pickle.load(open(file, 'rb'))[1:n];
```

Comment: This still loads the entire file - you're just selecting a portion of them (n-1, incidentally, not n) after you load.