# Load 8gb pickled file efficiently

Tags: json, python-3.x, pickle, dump

I Pickled a json/dictionary format data using the following code:

```py
with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as f:   
     pickle.dump(to_list, f)
```

The resultant pickled object is 8 GB! Now I am trying to load the file for some data manipulation/cleaning but it's taking a long time (~ 4 min) to load. I am using the following code to load the data:

```py
pickle_in = open("data.pkl","rb")   
data = pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

I want to reduce the load time.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: looks like somewhat related: [How can I speed up unpickling large objects if I have plenty of RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766685/how-can-i-speed-up-unpickling-large-objects-if-i-have-plenty-of-ram)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to store data in another format. Consider the following code. The very same data stored with pickle. The only difference is the format - dictionary of lists VS pandas dataframe. As you can see and try by yourself panas dataframe is loaded about 50 times faster. I guess the reason is parsing data into objects. So consider switching to more efficient data format.

```
import functools
import time
import pickle

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def measure_running_time(echo=True):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            t_1 = time.time()
            ans = func(*args, **kwargs)
            t_2 = time.time()
            if echo:
                print(f'{func.__name__}() running time is {t_2 - t_1:.2f} s')
            return ans
        return wrapped
    return decorator


def f_0():
    data = np.random.random((14_000, 1_000))  # 0.1 GB numpy array
    # print(data.nbytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024)
    # format 1 - dictionary of lists
    data_b = {idx: list(val) for idx, val in enumerate(data)}
    # format 2 - pandas dataframe
    data_p = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # save data
    with open('1.pickle', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(data_b, file)
    data_p.to_pickle('2.pickle')


@measure_running_time()
def f_1():
    with open('1.pickle', 'rb') as file:
        pickle.load(file)


@measure_running_time()
def f_2():
    pd.read_pickle('2.pickle')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # f_0()
    f_1()
    f_2()
```

Output:

```
f_1() running time is 5.52 s
f_2() running time is 0.11 s
```